# GeoStream is not assignable to parameter of type 'GeoRawProjection' in d3 API version 4

Tags: angular, d3.js, leaflet

In d3.geo [API 3](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Geo-Streams.md#stream-transforms), it has the function to project the geo location coordinates onto the map like leaflet.

for example the code in version 3 is like

```
var transform = d3.geo.transform({point: self.projectPoint});
          self._path = d3.geo.path().projection(transform);

projectPoint: function(x, y) {
      var point = MELBPARKING.Map.map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x));
      this.stream.point(point.x, point.y);
    }
```

Now I use the angular2 framework to build the leaflet map to project the coordinates in D3.js, the D3.js 's API is built upon [the version 4](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#geoTransform). I looked into the D3.js 's library, the geoTransform and geoProjection are exported

```
export {default as geoTransform} from "./src/transform";
export {default as geoProjection, projectionMutator as geoProjectionMutator} from "./src/projection/index";
```

In my angular2 project, I used d3.js and leaflet.js to build a leaflet map component, shown as below

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import {geoTransform,geoProjection} from "d3-geo";

export class MapsComponent implements OnInit {
   map;
   _path ;

   ngOnInit(){
      console.log('init map');
      this.map = L.map('mapid', {
      center: L.latLng(38, 15),
      zoom: 5,
      });
      this.map.setView(L.latLng(-37.81108500, 144.96269970), 18);
      var self = this;
      var transform = geoTransform({point: self.projectPoint})
      console.log(transform);
      self._path = geoProjection(transform);
   }

   projectPoint(x, y) {
       var point = this.map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y,x));
       this.map.stream.point(point.x, point.y);
   }
}
```

However the project met an error as below

```
    ERROR in /maps.component.ts (87,32): Argument of type '{ stream(s: 
GeoStream): { point: (x: any, y: any) => void; } & GeoStream; }' is not
 assignable to parameter of type 'GeoRawProjection'.

    Type '{ stream(s: GeoStream): { point: (x: any, y: any) => void; } &
 GeoStream; }' provides no match for the signature '(lambda: number, phi: 
number): [number, number]'.
```

what is the wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass your transform as the first argument to [d3.geoPath](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#geoPath), not d3.geoProjection. Per path.projection, this argument can be any projection stream (which is useful for planar transformations like scaling and translating), not just a spherical d3.geoProjection instance.